# QTranslate for Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-qtranslate

How to add qtranslate-support for custom post type? Just saving text with tags  OR add flag switcher.

My Custom Post Type field:

```
add_meta_box('project_rolesid', 'Roles box', 'project_roles', 'portfolio', 'normal');
<textarea id="portfolio_project_roles" cols="80" rows="7" name="portfolio_project_roles">'.$roles.'</textarea>
```

Trying to add suport by adding line

```
add_action('portfolio_project_roles','qtrans_useCurrentLanguageIfNotFoundShowAvailable', 0);
```

in `qtranslate_hooks.php`, but no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using tags is pretty straightforward. All data in qTranslate is stored between special `<!--:lang-->content<!--:-->` tags, wherein `lang` is the code for the language, like `en`, `ru`, `de`, etc.

The post edit UI is altered via qTranslate's heavy JavaScript. The JavaScript parses the content for preset fields and creates new controls. Before saving the same JavaScript does the opposite, merges the UI fields and wraps them up into the tags above. This simple behavior can be replicated by injecting additional JavaScript from your custom post type code to split your custom field into as many languages as you need, then merge them together, using [qtrans_integrate_*](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/qtranslate/trunk/qtranslate_javascript.php#L106), [qtrans_save](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/qtranslate/trunk/qtranslate_javascript.php#L348) and other existing odds and ends as a guide for your own code.

Again, this is very straightforward - split tags in your `#portfolio_project_roles`, for each language create `#portfolio_project_roles_{lang}` textareas and fill with split content, before saving merge back into one `#portfolio_project_roles` wrapping each content language payload into the tags.

When saved, your custom post type metadata in your database would look like this, for example: `"portfolio_roles" => "<!--:en-->Vladimir - Project Lead<!--:--><!--:ru-->Владимир - куратор проекта<!--:-->"`.  To display chunks of this data depending on the language, you have to use a couple of filters qTranslate provides, mainly: [`qtrans_useCurrentLanguageIfNotFoundShowAvailable`](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/qtranslate/trunk/qtranslate_hooks.php#L104) and the like, or even [`qtrans_use`](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/qtranslate/trunk/qtranslate_core.php#L747) directly.

```
<div id="content>
    <?php echo qtrans_useCurrentLanguageIfNotFoundShowAvailable(
                get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_roles', true ) ) );
    ?>
</div>
```

This will output the correct language split payload (don't forget to escape the output using `esc_html`).

A cleaner approach would be to use the [`meta filter`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/meta.php#L274) and hook it over the `qtrans_use*` functions. I'm sure there are other interesting approaches that can be taken, but the above should provide you with the basic outline of how things work. Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome! Work's pretty well without esc_html