# How to make custom post meta wp_editor translatable?

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta

I have custom post type named *soto_property* in which I have added three *wp_editor* as post meta, using this code -

```
 wp_editor( htmlspecialchars_decode($valueeee1),
               'propertyEditor1',
               $settings = array('textarea_name'=>'detail',
                                 'editor_class'=>'propertyEditor')
              );

    wp_editor( htmlspecialchars_decode($valueeee2),
               'propertyEditor2',
               $settings = array('textarea_name'=>'features',
                                 'editor_class'=>'propertyEditor')
              );

    wp_editor( htmlspecialchars_decode($valueeee3),
               'propertyEditor3',
               $settings = array('textarea_name'=>'text_to_pdf',
                                 'editor_class'=>'propertyEditor')
              );
```

Now I have installed `qtranslate` plugin to make my site Multilingual. This plugin automaticaly add Language tab in its default content editor. I want to add these languages tabs in my custom editor also, so it can save content in defined languages.

How can I do this.? Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

it looks as already answered [here on stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97889/qtranslate-for-custom-post-type) (really detailed way), as first you can try:

```
add_filter('soto_property','qtrans_convertURL');
```

Anyway, have a look here on [qtranslate slug plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-slug/), usually it save tons of troubles. And small note - if I were you, I would better use [mqTranslate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mqtranslate/) (which is based on qTranslate, but it's compatible with last version of WP)

Comment: Hey.thank for reply. I have added `add_filter('soto_property','qtrans_convertURL');`  in qtranslate_hook.php but nothing happened. and the URL which you suggested me that didn't make enough sense to me. I couldn't found out that what I have to do after reading that. Could you please explain me little more about the answer mentioned at that URL.?

Answer (score 1):

I have done custom post type with multiple content editors ready to translate, I have used [This Metabox Plugin](https://github.com/rilwis/meta-box) to add the meta boxes, this plugin allows you to create multiple meta boxes according to the theme requirements,  to achieve your requirements, 1st install this plugin [Here is the link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/meta-box/) 
Then add code as follows in your functions.php or separate file then include to functions.php

```
global $meta_boxes;
$meta_boxes   = array();

$meta_boxes[] = array(

    'id' => 'standard',
    'title' => __( 'Simple Editors', 'your-languge-key' ),
    'pages' => array( 'your-post-type' ),
    'context' => 'normal',
    'priority' => 'high',
    'autosave' => true,
    'fields' => array(
        array(
                'name' => __( 'Simple Editor', 'your-languge-key' ),
                'id'   => "{$prefix}home-bottom-content",
                'type' => 'wysiwyg',
                // Set the 'raw' parameter to TRUE to prevent data being passed through wpautop() on save
                'raw'  => true,
                'std'  => __( 'WYSIWYG default value', 'your-languge-key' ),

                // Editor settings, see wp_editor() function: look4wp.com/wp_editor
                'options' => array(
                    'textarea_rows' => 4, 
                    'teeny'         => true,
                    'media_buttons' => false, // mediabuttons to editor
                ),
            ),
    ),

);
/**
 * Register meta boxes
 *
 * @return void
 */
function rw_register_meta_boxes()
{
    global $meta_boxes;

    // Make sure there's no errors when the plugin is deactivated or during upgrade
    if ( class_exists( 'RW_Meta_Box' ) ) {
        foreach ( $meta_boxes as $meta_box ) {
            if ( isset( $meta_box['only_on'] ) && ! rw_maybe_include( $meta_box['only_on'] ) ) {
                continue;
            }

            new RW_Meta_Box( $meta_box );
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'rw_register_meta_boxes' );

/**
 * Check if meta boxes is included
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function rw_maybe_include( $conditions ) {
    // Include in back-end only
    if ( ! defined( 'WP_ADMIN' ) || ! WP_ADMIN ) {
        return false;
    }

    // Always include for ajax
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) {
        return true;
    }

    if ( isset( $_GET['post'] ) ) {
        $post_id = intval( $_GET['post'] );
    }
    elseif ( isset( $_POST['post_ID'] ) ) {
        $post_id = intval( $_POST['post_ID'] );
    }
    else {
        $post_id = false;
    }

    $post_id = (int) $post_id;
    $post    = get_post( $post_id );

    foreach ( $conditions as $cond => $v ) {
        // Catch non-arrays too
        if ( ! is_array( $v ) ) {
            $v = array( $v );
        }

        switch ( $cond ) {
            case 'id':
                if ( in_array( $post_id, $v ) ) {
                    return true;
                }
            break;
            case 'parent':
                $post_parent = $post->post_parent;
                if ( in_array( $post_parent, $v ) ) {
                    return true;
                }
            break;
            case 'slug':
                $post_slug = $post->post_name;
                if ( in_array( $post_slug, $v ) ) {
                    return true;
                }
            break;
            case 'category': //post must be saved or published first
                $categories = get_the_category( $post->ID );
                $catslugs = array();
                foreach ( $categories as $category )
                {
                    array_push( $catslugs, $category->slug );
                }
                if ( array_intersect( $catslugs, $v ) )
                {
                    return true;
                }
            break;
            case 'template':
                $template = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_wp_page_template', true );
                if ( in_array( $template, $v ) )
                {
                    return true;
                }
            break;
        }
    }

    // If no condition matched
    return false;
}
```

Here I have added only one editor, you can add number of editors by reusing editor filed. Hope this is solve your issue. good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I have used qranslate-x plugin which makes my custom wp_editor translatable on my custom post type page.